# How to retrieve stored proc data without the word "table" in the return value using c# web api

Tags: c#, json, asp.net-web-api, stored-procedures

I'm trying to pull some database rows to be consumed through an api using the code below:

```
DataSet ds = new DataSet();
using (SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection("data source=.; database=GiveTradeApp; integrated security=true;"))
{
    SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("sp_get_products_by_user", con);
    cmd.Parameters.Add("user_id", SqlDbType.Int).Value = id;
    cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;

    con.Open();
    SqlDataAdapter adp = new SqlDataAdapter();
    adp.SelectCommand = cmd;
    adp.Fill(ds);
}

var message = Request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.OK, ds);
return message;
```

It's all fine except when I try calling the function through postman, I get the json result format in:

```
{
  "Table": [
    {
      "some row": "some value",
      "some row": "some value"
    },
    {
      "another row": "another value",
      "another row": "another value"
    }
  ]
}
```

Could I retrieve it instead like so:

```
{
  {
    "some row": "some value",
    "some row": "some value"
  },
  {
    "another row": "another value",
    "another row": "another value"
  }
}
```

Comment: What you want isn't valid json - it could be if it was surrounded by [ ] instead of { }.

Comment: can i get the results without the data being inside the "Table" object? it would be cleaner if i could use it without reading inside the "Table" object and just straight through the rows and values

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use following method to get data in `JSON` format

**Method 1 :**

> For this first we need to download JSON.Net DLL. We can download it from Nuget.org and then import the Newtonsoft.JSON namespace into our page as in the following code. JSON.NET is a popular high-performance JSON framework for .NET.

```
using Newtonsoft.JSON;  


public string DataTableToJSONWithJSONNet(DataTable table)
{  
   string JSONString=string.Empty;  
   JSONString = JSONConvert.SerializeObject(table);  
   return JSONString;  
}
```

**Method 2 :**

```
public static string DataTableToJSONWithStringBuilder(DataTable table)
    {
        var JSONString = new StringBuilder();
        if (table.Rows.Count > 0)
        {
            JSONString.Append("[");
            for (int i = 0; i < table.Rows.Count; i++)
            {
                JSONString.Append("{");
                for (int j = 0; j < table.Columns.Count; j++)
                {
                    if (j < table.Columns.Count - 1)
                    {
                        JSONString.Append("\"" + table.Columns[j].ColumnName.ToString() + "\":" + "\"" + table.Rows[i][j].ToString() + "\",");
                    }
                    else if (j == table.Columns.Count - 1)
                    {
                        JSONString.Append("\"" + table.Columns[j].ColumnName.ToString() + "\":" + "\"" + table.Rows[i][j].ToString() + "\"");
                    }
                }
                if (i == table.Rows.Count - 1)
                {
                    JSONString.Append("}");
                }
                else
                {
                    JSONString.Append("},");
                }
            }
            JSONString.Append("]");
        }
        return JSONString.ToString();
    }
```

**Method 3 :**

```
 public string DataTableToJSONWithJavaScriptSerializer(DataTable table) 
 {  
    JavaScriptSerializer jsSerializer = new JavaScriptSerializer();  
    List < Dictionary < string, object >> parentRow = new List < Dictionary < string, object >> ();  
    Dictionary < string, object > childRow;  
    foreach(DataRow row in table.Rows) 
    {  
        childRow = new Dictionary < string, object > ();  
        foreach(DataColumn col in table.Columns) 
        {  
            childRow.Add(col.ColumnName, row[col]);  
        }  
        parentRow.Add(childRow);  
    }  
    return jsSerializer.Serialize(parentRow);  
}
```

And pass your DataSet as

```
 String JsonResult = DataTableToJSONWithJSONNet(ds.Tables[0])
 var message = Request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.OK, JsonResult );
    return message;
```